# How to write correlated sub query in Laravel 5.2 using Model class

Tags: laravel-5

I have done lot of search on internet before asking and i did not found any workable solution, So i am writing my question here. I want to retrieve users and count how many user live in same city from model(user). So to achieve this task i have to write correlated sub query (where inner query output depends on outer query).

**Efforts**

```
$users = '';
$noOfOccurance = User::select(\DB::raw('count(*)'))->where('city', $users[0]->city)->get();

$users= User::select('name', 'region', 'country', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude', \DB::raw('({$noOfOccurance->toSql()}) as no_of_occurance'))->where('id', '1')->mergeBindings($noOfOccurance->getQuery())->get();
```

but, i failed to do that. I getting `Uninitialized string offset: 0` and it is obvious to get as $user users not initialized and does not contains any thing.

**Sample query**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email,(select count(u1.id) from users u1 where last_name = u.last_name) FROM users as u where id = 2
```

**Output of the above query**

[image: output from query]

**Update**

```
User::select('name', 'region', 'country', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude', \DB::raw(User::select(\DB::raw('count(*)'))->where('city', $users[0]->city))->where('id', '1'))->get();
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your requirement based on this information. try to describe more about your problem and related models as well.

Comment: Uninitialized string offset throws when you doesn't supply an argument for prepared statement, try to think by this way

Comment: Ok. I have updated the details and a sample query that i want to generate from laravel. In inner query the last_name = 'Kumar' needs to come from outer query.

Comment: remove get() from $noOfOccurance = User::select(\DB::raw('count(*)'))->where('city', $users[0]->city)->get();

Comment: It give me Undefined variable: users error. I have also tried different way. as i have updated in my question.